# How to apply replacement with regex from partial results to full content?

Tags: java, regex, replace

I have a regex and replacement routine with several steps. It works fine and my desired content is found and replaced. But I don't know how to set the partial replaced content back into the full content.

I'd like to cross out the numbers in certain tags, here 'number' and 'otherNumber'.

```
String content = "complex content number="456" with many linebreaks\n
   signal number="123" test otherNumber="A1" endsignal\n
   more complex content";
```

Result should be:

```
complex content number="456" with many linebreaks\n
signal number="XXX" test otherNumber="XX" endsignal\n
more complex content
```

Note that only the numbers in a certain row are masked out.

For the row where I want to replace the values, there is a signal word in front and a signal word at the end.
With the first matcher `signal.*?endsignal` I extract the row where the replacement should take place, because other rows may contain the same tags.

Then I run another matcher only on that row with lookahead `(?<=number=").*?(")` and replace the found content for the `number` tag.

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("signal.*?endsignal").matcher(content);
while (m.find()) {
    String match = m.group(1);
    match = Pattern.compile("(?<=number=").*?(")").matcher(match).replaceAll("XXX");
}
Sysout(content); //still content has number="123" not masked.
```

So far so good, the replacement works fine in my code (don't count me on the example here, just to make my problems clear).

**Problem**: I now have a `String match` that contains the replaced content. How do I get the replaced line back into my full `String content` variable? Because it still contains the old unreplaced content.

Comment: I don't know if I understood right: You replaced numbers, say `123`, with `XXX` and then you want it back?

Comment: No, I want to set the replaced string line `signal number="XXX" test otherNumber="XX" endsignal\n` into the `String content` full content string. Because, as of end of the routine, `String content` will still contain the old unreplaced values...

Comment: Is `number` and `otherNumber` mandatory in `signal` line? Also is their order always same?

Comment: I only want to replace values in number tag if the tag is present, otherwise not. So probably they are not considered to be mandatory, also order is not necessarily the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't... not until the end:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String content = "complex content number=\"456\" with many linebreaks\n" +
                "signal number=\"123\" test otherNumber=\"XX\" endsignal\n" +
                "more complex content";

        Matcher m = Pattern.compile("signal.*?endsignal").matcher(content);
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        while (m.find()) {
            String match = m.group(0); // the whole match... including start/end signal.
            match = Pattern.compile("(?<=number=\").*?(\")").matcher(match).replaceAll("XXX");

            m.appendReplacement(sb, match);
        }
        m.appendTail(sb);
        content = sb.toString();       

        System.out.println(content);
    }
```

See [Javadoc for Matcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement%28java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String%29)

## EDIT

```
    private static final Pattern numberpat = Pattern.compile("(?<=number=\")(.+?)(?=\")");
    private static final Pattern linepat = Pattern.compile("signal.*?endsignal");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String content = "complex content number=\"456\" with many linebreaks\n" +
                "signal number=\"123\" test otherNumber=\"A2\" endsignal\n" +
                "more complex content";

        Matcher m = linepat.matcher(content);
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        while (m.find()) {
            String match = m.group(0); // the whole match... including start/end signal.
            m.appendReplacement(sb, "");
            Matcher nmat = numberpat.matcher(match); // note the new regular expression with only one matching group
            while (nmat.find()) {
                nmat.appendReplacement(sb, nmat.group(0).replaceAll(".", "X"));
            }
            nmat.appendTail(sb);
        }
        m.appendTail(sb);
        content = sb.toString();       

        System.out.println(content);
    }
```

using two loops.

Note that the regex does the 'right thing' and does not match the `A1` in `otherNumber="A1"` in that it **does not match** because it looks for lower-case 'N' in 'otherNumber'

If you want to match any-case, I recommend `"(?<=[Nn]umber=\")(.+?)(?=\")"`

Comment: Ty so much, does exactly what I was asking for. One more question: is it possible to get the "size" of the inner match, so that I know how many digits/chars were matched, and thus how many "X" masks I would have to replace so that character count is not changed?

Comment: This is great! Sidequestion: does it have any impact eg on the execution times to use only one matching group in the number regex?